# Library installed and shown in conda, but not usable in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, python-imaging-library

The pillow library is installed via conda, and the status is verified in the jupyter notebook.  However when I try to import pillow library in the same jupyter notebook instance, I cannot find this library.

I tried to manually run jupyter notebook cli in conda environment (with pillow installed), as well using anaconda GUI shortcuts, none of them could find pillow library.

```py
!conda list pillow
import pillow
```

Output

```py
# packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\jupyter:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pillow                    6.0.0            py37h9a613e6_0    conda-forge
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-dc0fbd63c36f> in <module>
      1 get_ipython().system('conda list pillow')
----> 2 import pillow

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pillow'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pillow is a fork of `PIL` (Python Imaging Library) so it can't be imported, it's PIL that is imported.

Use:-

```
import PIL
```

or import any specific module by

```
from PIL import Module_name
```

Comment: Thank you, I see.  Just checked for python3, pillow is in fact used under the name of PIL.  Thank you